# OpenApi generator creates Enum properties with same name

Tags: typescript, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

My OpenApi Generator (ver. 6.4.0) for TypeScript
is producing double properties with same name in enums.

Swagger input:

```
"objectRole":{"type":"string","enum":["-1","1","2"]}
```

Generated TypeScript output:

```
export const ObjectRoleEnum = {
    _1: '-1',
    _1: '1',
    _2: '2'
} as const;
```

Of course it throws this error then:

```
TS1117: An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name.
```

The Swagger input is generated itself from an unnamed Java Enum. So I cant change the Swagger definition here.

How can I configure the generator or the template to respect numeric signs in strings like minus for Enums? And avoid double names.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

I override all Enum .mustache templates like this:

```
{{#isEnum}}
/**
* @export
* @enum {string}
*/
export enum {{classname}}{{enumName}} {
{{#allowableValues}}
    {{#enumVars}}
    {{{name}}}_{{-index}} = {{{value}}}{{^-last}},{{/-last}}
    {{/enumVars}}
{{/allowableValues}}
}{{/isEnum}}{{/vars}}{{/hasEnums}}
```

focus on:
**{{{name}}}_{{-index}} = ...**

instead of:
**{{{name}}} = ...**

results in:

```
export enum ObjectRoleEnum {
    _1_1 = '-1',
    _1_2 = '1',
    _2_3 = '2'
}
```